# Choosing the correct hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample

I was trying out some questions on hypothesis testing when some questions started challenging me. Here is an example:

A lot of product X is to be rejected if the temperature of the lot is greater than $75$ degree Celsius and is to be expected if the case is otherwise? (Then the question gives some data regarding a sample and asks) Should the lot be rejected?

What should be by alternate hypothesis in the question. How would I know what the researcher wants to prove through his research?

One more question on the same lines:
A company will open a new store in the area if more than $5 \%$ of the people of the area had good opinion about its products. (Then some data is given regarding a sample that we collected and asks) Should the company open store in the area?

Kindly tell me the thought procedure involved in the process of choosing null and alternate hypotheses.

Comment: If the lot is to be rejected on the basis of a measured temperature then there is not much to hypothesise about. Measure the temperature and reject or not.

Comment: There's a lot of wisdom in that comment by Michael Lew. If you have the whole population and get that they are warmer than $75 ^\circ $C, then they're warmer than $75 ^\circ $C. There's no statistics to do here. If you have a sample and are interested in the population from which the sampled observations were drawn, then you can do statistics and conduct hypothesis testing.

Comment: @MichaelLew 's comment also applies to your second question. There is no hypothesis here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the difference is only interesting to you if the difference is in a particular direction, so one-sided testing would be appropriate. If you did two-sided testing, I'm imagining this conversation with your boss.

**YOU**: "...and then after hypothesis testing, I conclude that it was not 75 degrees celcius, and 5% of people did not have a positive opinion of the products. I rock!"

**BOSS**: "Was it hotter or colder than 75 degrees?"

**YOU**: "I didn't test that, just if it's 75 degrees."

**BOSS**: "Did fewer or more than 5% of people have a positive opinion?"

**YOU**: "I didn't test that, just if it's 5%."

**BOSS**: "How enlightening..."

If you do one-sided testing, you can answer her questions.

For the first situation:

$$H_0: \theta \le 75 ^\circ C$$

$$H_a: \theta > 75 ^\circ C$$

For the second situation:

$$H_0: \theta \le 5\%$$

$$H_a: \theta > 5\% $$

In both cases, $\theta$ is whatever it is that you're measuring. It's a common variable to use in statistics, and it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with angles like you may be thinking from trig or physics class.

**NOTE**: Many teahers, particularly in intro classes, will write the following:

$$H_0: \theta = 5\% $$

$$H_a: \theta > 5\% $$

This is equivalent to what I wrote above.